# VSCode Extension: get a files old and new versions

Tags: typescript, git, visual-studio-code, diff, vscode-extensions

I am trying to develop a VSCode extension which requires the current open file and same file from previous git revision/commit. Which is same as clicking the open changes button in vs code.

[image: open changes icon]

I Tried using SCM and QuickDiffProvider as shown in this [sample-extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/source-control-sample), but its giving "unable to resolve resource" when trying to open the old file in vscode.

[image]

---

snippet from **extension.ts**

```
let folder: string = vscode.env.appRoot;
let scm: vscode.SourceControl | undefined;
if (vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders) {
    let rootUri = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri;
    scm = vscode.scm.createSourceControl("MyDiff", "MyDiff", rootUri);
    folder = rootUri.fsPath;
    var repo = new Repository(vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0]);
    scm.quickDiffProvider = repo;
    let changedResources = scm.createResourceGroup("workingTree", "Changes");
    // repo.getResourceStates().then((result) => {
    //     changedResources.resourceStates = result;
    // });
    // context.subscriptions.push(changedResources);
    var currentlyOpenTabfileUri = vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.document.uri;
    if(currentlyOpenTabfileUri){
        if(repo.provideOriginalResource){
            const repositoryUri = repo.provideOriginalResource(currentlyOpenTabfileUri, null);
            console.log(repositoryUri);
            console.log(currentlyOpenTabfileUri);
            try{
                vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.open', currentlyOpenTabfileUri);
                vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.open', repositoryUri);
                vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.diff', repositoryUri, currentlyOpenTabfileUri,  `Old - New`);
            }
            catch(err){
                console.error(err);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Repository.ts**

```
export const JSFIDDLE_SCHEME = 'MyDiff';
import { QuickDiffProvider, Uri, CancellationToken, ProviderResult, WorkspaceFolder, workspace, window, env } from "vscode";
import * as path from 'path';


export class Repository implements QuickDiffProvider {

    constructor(private workspaceFolder: WorkspaceFolder) { }

    provideOriginalResource?(uri: Uri, token: CancellationToken|null): ProviderResult<Uri> {
        // converts the local file uri to jsfiddle:file.ext
        const relativePath = workspace.asRelativePath(uri.fsPath);
        return Uri.parse(`${JSFIDDLE_SCHEME}:${relativePath}`);
    }

    /**
     * Enumerates the resources under source control.
     */
    provideSourceControlledResources(): Uri[] {
        return [
            Uri.file(this.createLocalResourcePath('json'))
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Creates a local file path in the local workspace that corresponds to the part of the 
     * fiddle denoted by the given extension.
     *
     * @param extension fiddle part, which is also used as a file extension
     * @returns path of the locally cloned fiddle resource ending with the given extension
     */
    createLocalResourcePath(extension: string) {
        return path.join(this.workspaceFolder.uri.fsPath, extension);
    }
}
```

**Debug Console Output:**

```
Congratulations, your extension "vscode-test-diff" is now active!
h {scheme: 'MyDiff', authority: '', path: 'test', query: '', fragment: '', …}
h {scheme: 'file', authority: '', path: '/c:/dummy/test', query: '', fragment: '', …}
```

---

**What I am looking for, in short:** 
I want to get file contents of the file in left side view (old) and right side view (new) as shown in openChange, in my extension. The purpose is to write a custom compare method and store the result in html format instead of showing as diff with side by side compare.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling so much to find alternative solution to get the diff of file, I found that we can use `vscode.editors`, to access all the open editors.

**Example:** In git diff we will have 2 editors (left: old and right: new), so we can use the following code to access old and new content.

```
if (editors.length === 2) {
    oldContent = editors[0].document.getText();
    newContent = editors[1].document.getText();
}
```

If we use git lens, then we can get the diff of older commits also with same code which is an added benefit (at least for my extension).

The only catch in this way is it will also work if 2 editors are opened in 2 columns (which is actually fine for my extension)